# How to design anti-corruption layer in DDD

Tags: c#, design-patterns, domain-driven-design, json, soap

I'm getting ready to create an integration with a major external system and was wondering if my understanding of the design pattern for this in domain driven design was solid.

Considerations:
External System serves SOAP, mine's a web api 2 solution.
Full CRUD operations across many SOAP methods

My thoughts:

1. Create a giant facade class that receives the data.
2. Have each method in the facade call an adapter that then transforms the data from SOAP to a domain model.
3. Call the adapter in infrastructure service class and pass it up into the domain.

Concerns:
Does this pattern sound correct? Is there a more fitting one for creating a clearly defined bounded context?

I'd be using infrastructure as a pass through to the domain, it wouldn't be doing much at this point, another option is to pass the adapter directly to a factory though I prefer going through infrastructure.

Conceptual Diagram I'm basing my design on:

[image: Domain-Driven Design: Tackling Complexity in the Heart of Software By Eric Evans]

Comment: What do you mean by "correct?"  The "correct" approach is the one that best meets your specific requirements.  Does this approach best meet your specific requirements?  What prevents you from simply using the existing API as-is?

Comment: @Robert yeah, I realize there's no "correct" way to architecture, on the flip side, there's best practices for implementing patterns, thereby it is safe to infer something like: "Does this design make sense?"  See OP considerations for why I'm hesitant to use the API as-is.

Comment: You do't necessarily need everything in that diagram.  The diagram is merely illustrative.

Comment: My question is why are you looking for someone (strange) say to you *seems fine to me go ahead*?. Reading the question I come to the conclusion that you are not looking for answers, you are looking for aproval (IMO). What is really concern you?

Comment: One thing I'd point out is to make sure that your subsystem doesn't depend on the anticorruption layer (the arrows should point the other way), otherwise you still end up with a strong dependency on the other subsystem. The way to do that is to have your system define ServiceA & ServiceB interfaces as suitable abastractions, and then have the AC layer implement them, so that your subsystem has no idea about the AC layer.

Comment: @Laiv you can say that about any design question, doesn't mean they shouldn't be asked + they often get voted down on root SOE.  And yes all design questions come down to yes this a good design, or no a better approach is x.  However, if there's a better board for code design, that'd work too.

Comment: @Filip interfaces are an excellent idea as I do have a DI container, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I'm not saying you should not ask. Just that asking for approval is different than asking for concrete things. Asking for better designs is a  too broad question given our limited understanding/knowledge of the system/problem. We don't have all the details. On the other hand, worth nothing taking forward the actual design (to do a proof test) and see its strengths and weakness. The weakness will lead you to more precise questions and hence precise answers. Altogether to better design :-)

Comment: @Laiv it's a design for a very specific module of DDD, I can't imagine I'm the first person to build an AC either, so other folks might have this pattern implemented and might already have some lessons learned to share. How is my question different from say https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/294773/help-understanding-modeling-in-domain-driven-design?rq=1 ?

Comment: anti-corruption layer....Worst name ever for a pattern. Might be a good name if it was a pattern to prevent data from being corrupted...but nooooooo!

Comment: @Dunk The name `anti-corruption layer` is, in fact, well suited since it denotes a set of logic that is used to prevent model in one Bounded Context from becoming infected with model/Ubiquitous language from another Bounded Context.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An Anti-corruption layer is a class/ package/component that take as an input the external model and it produces the local model.

For example, in a CQRS architecture, it can be implemented as a `Saga`: would take the events generated by the `aggregates` in the external `bounded context` and would create `commands` for `aggregates` in the `local bounded context`.

Comment: That makes sense, so I'll stand up a project for it and have it talk to the domain via interfaces, your Saga is my facade I believe, the adapters / translators seem to be optional.